# Array Sorting in php for decimal values

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

Below is a php variable numbers which contains an array i need to sort in Ascending order and result which i want is below that. Please help. 
$numbers = array(3.11,1, 2, 3.1,3.10,3,3.2,3.3);

result i want:

1
2
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.10
3.11

Comment: If you open php documentation and search for 'sort', you'll see a lot of functions.

Comment: @KanchoIliev: which sorting will be fiting to my condition?

Comment: Many of them. I'm sure if you start reading you'll easy find. My recommendation is to use the simple one.

Comment: i tried it but the result which i am getting is 1, 2, 3, 3.10, 3.1, 3.11, 3.2, 3.3 but what i want is 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.10, 3.11

Comment: @KanchoIliev : i am newbie i tried it but the result which i am getting is 1, 2, 3, 3.10, 3.1, 3.11, 3.2, 3.3 but what i want is 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.10, 3.11

Comment: If you have special conditions it is good to use uasort function. It lets you to define you own condition for ordering. It is easy - refer to its documentation.

Comment: @KanchoIliev : sorry i asked wrong question now i have corrected the question please check my array order is different.

Comment: OK, but my answer is the same :) - uasort will resolve your problem

Comment: @KanchoIliev: can u give me an example because i am newbie to php

Comment: Make a try by your self. In case you can't resolve - show us your codeand we will help. There are a lot of examples of using uasort in the documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

If you setup your array with strings, you can use [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) function to get result you want

```
$numbers = array('1', '2', '3', '3.1', '3.2', '3.3', '3.10', '3.11');
natsort($numbers);
print_r($numbers);
```

Now, when you init array with numbers, there is no difference between 3.10 and 3.1

[**demo**](https://eval.in/922496)

Comment: Thanks for the help but i also need to echo each value in that order only

Comment: https://eval.in/922541 - it's your order. isn't it?

Comment: Yes, But i need to echo those values in that order. Is it possible?

Comment: https://eval.in/922578

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort()` function

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.10, 3.11);
sort($numbers);
var_dump($numbers);
```

Comment: i tried it but the result which i am getting is 1, 2, 3, 3.10, 3.1, 3.11, 3.2, 3.3 but what i want is 1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.10, 3.11

Comment: sorry i asked wrong question now i have corrected the question please check my array order is different.

Answer (score -1):

### You just need to use `sort() function`.

For e.g.

```
$numbers = array(1, 2, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.10, 3.11);
sort($numbers);
print_r($numbers);
```

Output:
1 2 3 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.10 3.11

Comment: sorry i asked wrong question now i have corrected the question please check my array order is different.

Comment: Your float number have unequal decimal points, you need to keep all float values in same decimal point.
eg. php doesn't consider trailing 0's in decimal point, you have to make your 3.1 to 3.01, 3.2 to 3.02 likewise. Then use sort you'll get your answer.