# Natural array sorting with proper decimal support in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to sort an array with numbers in natural order, so numbers with a bigger value come after smaller ones like this:

```
php > $numbers = array('10 Apple', '2 Grapes', '3 Apples', '3.2 Apples', '3.1 Apples', '3.3 Apples', '3.10 Apples', '3.11 Apples', 'Lots of Apples');
php > natsort($numbers);
```

This is what I get as result, which is not the result I need, decimals are not threated correctly.

```
php > print_r($numbers);
Array
(
    [1] => 2 Grapes
    [2] => 3 Apples
    [4] => 3.1 Apples
    [3] => 3.2 Apples
    [5] => 3.3 Apples
    [6] => 3.10 Apples
    [7] => 3.11 Apples
    [0] => 10 Apple
    [8] => Lots of Apples
)
```

There is already a similar question [Array Sorting in php for decimal values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47899840/array-sorting-in-php-for-decimal-values) but no fitting answer was found there.

The expected output for a property sorting would be

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2 Grapes
    [2] => 3 Apples
    [4] => 3.1 Apples
    [6] => 3.10 Apples
    [7] => 3.11 Apples
    [3] => 3.2 Apples
    [5] => 3.3 Apples
    [0] => 10 Apple
    [8] => Lots of Apples
)
```

So I would kind of expect `natsort()` do to exactly that, but it looks like it is buggy and I have to implement a similar logic by my self? Is that correct?

One solution I am thinking of is to reformat the numbers somehow to fixed precision and hope that `natsort()` works then, but I am wondering if there are easier solutions or PHP-builtin ones.

I tried https://github.com/awssat/numbered-string-order which is very interesting but also does not support decimals.

Comment: Use `usort()` with a comparison function that extracts the numbers from the strings and compares them.

Comment: If all the strings end with `Apples`, why don't you just remove that and sort it numerically?

Comment: Thanks all, I improve the question a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of your specification so please test this, but [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php) seems like it can be used to run a `natsort` variant in `usort`. If both strings passed to the comparator start with float numbers, then cast them to floats and use the spaceship, otherwise, default to `strnatcmp`.

```php
<?php

$numbers = ['10 Apple', '2 Grapes', '3 Apples', '3.2 Apples', '3.1 Apples', '3.3 Apples', '3.10 Apples', '3.11 Apples', 'Lots of Apples'];

usort($numbers, function ($a, $b) {
    if (preg_match("~^\d*\.\d+\b~", $a, $m)) {
        $aa = (float)$m[0];

        if (preg_match("~^\d*\.\d+\b~", $b, $m)) {
            $bb = (float)$m[0];
            return $aa <=> $bb;
        }
    }

    return strnatcmp($a, $b);
});
print_r($numbers);
```